# How do I use Add a Keyconfig Preset?

Tags: shortcut

In the Preference > Keymap

It says Blender v + -
So I press + There's a dialog that asks for a name of the new keyconfig preset.

I type a new name, I call it "Swap MMB"

I make the changes in the shortcuts.
It behaves like I want.
But when I go back to "Blender" in the list, it has also changed to the same modifications I did with "Swap MMB"

Changing from one or the other does not swap the keyconfig. As if they were both the same. If I reset the Blender key config my "swap MMB" also resets. So I must be doing something wrong.

How do I use Add Keyconfig to make my own custom keyconfig and keep Blender's default keyconfig unchanged?

Comment: What exactly are you changing? There might be a conflict with another keybinding. See the very bottom of this page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html

Comment: @Psyonic I'm swapping the MMB = panview and MMB+shift = rotate view, nothing else. The page doesn't seem to give me any clarity on how or why my own keyconfig affects Blender default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is not a preset it is only what Blender has become.

If you make a custom keyconfig and call it "Swap MMB" and change keyconfig that is what Blender and Blender 2 7 X and others are now.

In order to change everything back to default you have to make a new entry and call it something else. EG "Default" change all of keyconfig back to the original configuration, now all Blender and Blender 2 7 X and others are also.